# Why does creating an android wear AVD does not work for me?

Tags: android, wear-os

When I try to create an wear-AVD, I am facing following error:

> The skin directory does not point to a valid skin

The finish button and most other buttons are disabled, so no way for me to change anything or create the AVD.

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Upgraded Android studio, build tools, etc and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue with Android Studio 3.3 and was all up to date. I had the same error message showing, but exiting and re-entering the VDM cleared the message with no changes. Also, I may...or may not...have been staring at the disabled 'Next' button instead of 'Finish'.

For throughness, I got the error message with Android 9.0, downloaded the 8.0 (US) image the next try, then the 9.0 skin error went away...not sure if downloading 8.0 image made any difference. Hope this helps someone.

Thanks for updating with a reply instead of deleting.